# Shortcut key in Eclipse to fix Checkstyle warnings "Parameter xxx should be final"

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

Is there any shortcut key to fix all the issues shown with the warning `Parameter xxx should be final`? In my application the same warning is shown 134 times. See the below code:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object result) { // Parameter result should be final    
}
```

Is there any shortcut to fix this warning?

I am Using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Select all code(`ctrl+a`) and press `ctrl+1` and `Enter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To see problems tabs go to menu `Window` > `Show View` > `Problems`
- Right-click on warning in Problems tab (e.g. "Parameter result Should be final")
- Choose "Quick Fix"
- In the "Quick Fix" window that opens up, select a fix type
- Click "Select All" to select all files that need the fix.
- Hit "Finish" to apply the fix.

Comment: all the warnings are showing in checkstyle violation view..I am not able to see in problems tab..can you help out..thanks for your help

Comment: check my edit, first step will help you find out problems tab

Comment: thanks(+1)..in info(under problems tab) it shows only (100 info) thats why i am unable to see all the info..i removed the limit under configure content..

Answer (score 3):

FYI, in Eclipse you can also configure a "Save Action" to automatically apply the `final` modifier to all parameters if possible.

Go to *Window → Preferences → Java → Editor → Save Actions* and click *Configure* next to *Additional Actions*. Then on the "Code Style" tab, select "use 'final' modifier where possible", and check 'Parameter'.

This may help keeping your code compliant in the future. The save actions can also be applied to the entire workspace at once by using the "Clean Up" feature available in *Java → Code Style → Clean Up*.